# Why does assigning an Object to another link them but the same doesn't apply for Strings

Tags: java

I've created a class called `Test` that has a constructor and one instance variable `String name`:

```
class Test {

    String name;

    Test(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I instantiate it like this:

```
    Test first = new Test("First");
    Test second = first;

    first.name = "Change First";
    System.out.println("First: " + first.name);
    System.out.println("Second: " + second.name);
```

... and predictably get this:

```
First: Change First
Second: Change First
```

This makes sense to me. I'm assigning the second Object to the same memory location referenced in the first - when I change the first, the second changes and vice versa.

Take this:

```
    String x = new String("Hello");
    String y = x;

    x = new String("Change");
    System.out.println("x: " + x);
    System.out.println("y: " + y);
```

The above gives the output:

```
x: Change
y: Hello
```

Why is this? They're both extend the `Object` class, so why do they behave so differently? Do any other `Object` derivatives behave like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
Test first = new Test("First");
Test second = first;

first = new Test("First");
first.name = "Change First";
System.out.println("First: " + first.name);
System.out.println("Second: " + second.name);
```

And you'll get:

```
First: Change First
Second: First
```

It's got nothing to do with it being a string versus an object. You are changing which object `x` points to with `x = new String("Change");`, rather than changing the contents of the original object. With `first.name = "Change First";` you aren't changing which object it points to; you are changing the contents of the object.

As strings are immutable in Java, you cannot change their contents; you will always be changing the reference instead.

Comment: Makes sense. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334518/java-strings-string-s-new-stringsilly) interesting reading also.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assigning the second Object to the same memory location referenced in the first

There is no "second object."  `first` and `second` are not objects.  They are object *references*.  Your program created an object when it called `new Test("First")`, and it stored a reference to that object in the `first` variable.  Then it copied the value of the `first` variable (i.e., it copied the *reference*) to the `second` variable.

At that point, each of the two variables refers to the same object, and when your program executed `first.name = "Change First";`, it modified that one and only object.

---

> [so, explain this...]

```
String x = new String("Hello");
String y = x;

x = new String("Change");
System.out.println("x: " + x);
System.out.println("y: " + y);
```

Your second example creates two objects. It created the first when it called `new String("Hello")`.  Then it created another when it called `new String("Change")`.

Once again, `x` and `y` are not `String` objects.  They are object *references*. Your second example leaves `x` holding a reference to the second `String` that it created, and it leaves `y` holding a reference to the first one.